# Ckeditor helper error in bonefire framework

Tags: javascript, php, backbonefire

I tried to integrate ck editor for my project. But it show some error massages.
I can't config those errors.
Controller  public function ckeditor()

```
   $this->load->helper('ckeditor_helper');
 //print_r($this->load->helper('ckeditor_helper'));

    //Ckeditor's configuration
    $data['ckeditor'] = array(

        //ID of the textarea that will be replaced
        'id'    =>  'content',
        'path'  =>  './assets/js/ckeditor',

        //Optionnal values
        'config' => array(
            'toolbar'   =>  "Full",     //Using the Full toolbar
            'width'     =>  "550px",    //Setting a custom width
            'height'    =>  '100px',    //Setting a custom height

        ),

        //Replacing styles from the "Styles tool"
        'styles' => array(

            //Creating a new style named "style 1"
            'style 1' => array (
                'name'      =>  'Blue Title',
                'element'   =>  'h2',
                'styles' => array(
                    'color'     =>  'Blue',
                    'font-weight'   =>  'bold'
                )
            ),

            //Creating a new style named "style 2"
            'style 2' => array (
                'name'  =>  'Red Title',
                'element'   =>  'h2',
                'styles' => array(
                    'color'         =>  'Red',
                    'font-weight'       =>  'bold',
                    'text-decoration'   =>  'underline'
                )
            )               
        )

    );

    $data['ckeditor_2'] = array(

        //ID of the textarea that will be replaced
        'id'    =>  'content_2',
        'path'  =>  './assets/js/ckeditor',

        //Optionnal values
        'config' => array(
            'width'     =>  "550px",    //Setting a custom width
            'height'    =>  '100px',    //Setting a custom height
            'toolbar'   =>  array(  //Setting a custom toolbar
                array('Bold', 'Italic'),
                array('Underline', 'Strike', 'FontSize'),
                array('Smiley'),
                '/'
            )
        ),

        //Replacing styles from the "Styles tool"
        'styles' => array(

            //Creating a new style named "style 1"
            'style 3' => array (
                'name'      =>  'Green Title',
                'element'   =>  'h3',
                'styles' => array(
                    'color'     =>  'Green',
                    'font-weight'   =>  'bold'
                )
            )

        )
    );      
   // Template::set('toolbar_title', 'Create New Event');
    Template::set_view('sport_events/ckeditor');
    Template::set('ckeditor',$data);
    Template::render();

}
```

Views ckeditor.php(This is my view page.just i call ckeditor.js and pass controller function array to views)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/asset/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/asset/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>

 <?php 
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($ckeditor);
 echo '</pre>';
  ?>       
 <textarea name="content" id="contents" ><p>Example data</p></textarea>
 <?php echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor); ?>
<textarea name="content_2" id="content_2" ><p>Example data</p></textarea>
<?php echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor_2); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was I didn't load correct place to ckeditor folder.
path should be public folder